# Django URL directing to wrong view

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

I am creating a Django application and have a couple URL'S

```
path('survey/<url_id>/<token>/', views.take_questionnaire, name='take-survey'),
path('survey/results/<url_id>/', views.view_results, name='view-results'),
```

I am trying to access the 'view-results' url -
http://127.0.0.1:8000/survey/results/lqH16jwM19Y6LLd/ - but for some reason this is triggering the 'take-survey' url.  If i change the order of the urls they seem to work, but im curious as to what is causing this.

I have never encountered this before, maybe i missed something when learning about django urls. Could someone explain why the first URL is getting triggered rather than the second?

Comment: The urls are very similar. If you change it to `path('survey/results/view/<url_id>/', views.view_results, name='view-results')`, it will be work.

Comment: Because `results` is a fine candidate for `<url_id>` which has no specification in given pattern so any text suffices.

Comment: Yes, this is what I thought. Would there be a way for me to specify that <url_id> must have 15 characters exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The urls are very similar.

All two urls match strings on second and third place.

If you change `view-results` to:

```
path('survey/results/view/<url_id>/', views.view_results, name='view-results'),
```

It will be work.

Look also at [**examples**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#example) from Django.

Answer (score 0):

Move the `view-results` route above the `take-survey` route.

url patterns are parsed in order and `take-survey` is being returned because the url `/survey/results/lqH16jwM19Y6LLd/` fits `survey/<url_id>/<token>/` as well as the `view-results` pattern.

Changing the order ensures any url `/survey/results/some-id/` will always go to `view-results`.

```py
path('survey/results/<url_id>/', views.view_results, name='view-results'),
path('survey/<url_id>/<token>/', views.take_questionnaire, name='take-survey'),
```